# Get active trails's siblings in menus

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I'm developing a custom theme using sub-theme just for learning purpose. In custom theme, I have added a custom block in which I need to display main menus' sub items if in_active_trail. I have already tried many times and wasted a lot time but unsuccessful.

1. Block **should display** when Level 1 is in_active_trails and it has child(s).
2. Block **should not display** when Level 1 in_active_trails but it has no child.
3. If any **Level 2** is current page, display Level 2 and 3 menu items expect level 1.
4. Same as ***point 3***, if **Level 3** is current page then display level 3 and 2 items.

See attached image below for more understanding what I want to do.

**Main Menu hierarchy**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block). Install and configure it.

It works for me.